# catkin setup.sh overwrites PATH environment variable?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the groovy installation and tutorial.

I source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash in my .bashrc.

I then set up catkin workspace and run catkin_make.

The resulting devel/setup.bash, when sourced, eliminates the /opt/ros/groovy/bin reference that was in my PATH environment variable... meaning I can not continue with the tutorial which is about rospack.

Should the catkin workspace setup.sh be overwriting the PATH environment variable like this? The catkin manual says it should respect already-sourced script like /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51647/catkin-setup.sh-overwrites-path-environment-variable?/) by [payneio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3919/payneio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ahhh... I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had initially gone deeper into the documentation (as suggested) here:
[www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Overlays](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Overlays)

The process it explains was causing my failure:

$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ rosws init --catkin ~/catkin_ws/src /opt/ros/groovy
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ catkin_make
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

Even if I ensure /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash was installed previously.

To get back on track in the tutorial, I deleted the ~/catkin_ws directory, re-sourced /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash and just did the basic tutorial steps of:
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [payneio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3919/payneio/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure that after changing your .bashrc, you started a new terminal? Else the change in the .bashrc did not take effect, which would explain your error.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3